# NuGet package not copying files and transform files as expected

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I am trying to understand how NuGet packages work so that I can package some of my repeatedly used source for future projects.
I am working with a simple class library (.Net Foundation) and using the CLI to make the nuspec file and then packing from the CLI I get a nuget package that installs the Class Library DLL perfectly.

But now I want to add a transform to the App.Config that includes a connection string and I want to copy a simple readme type file to the destination project.
Using the following nuspec file the readme does not install to the readme folder as expected (doesn't install at all) and I can't get any of the app.config.transforms to work at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
<id>$id$</id>
<version>$version$</version>
<title>$title$</title>
<authors>$author$</authors>
<owners>$author$</owners>
<requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
<description>$description$</description>
<releaseNotes>Stuff</releaseNotes>
<copyright>Copyright 2019</copyright>
<tags>123 1234</tags>
 </metadata>
  <files>
 <file src="app.config.transform" target="content\app.config.transform" />
<file src="Model\State1.cs" target="content\State1.cs"/>
<file src="new.txt" target="content\new.txt"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

Where should I put the transform files? It seems that they should be in a content folder in my source project but that isn't working. When I pack the nuget package I get an error about the files not being inside the content folder even though they clearly are.

With the above nuspec file I get an error:

> Access to the path 'C:\Users\ *UserName* \.nuget\packages\MyDLLProject.lookups\1.1.7041.17482\content' is denied.

Why is that?

Comment: [Here are the docs on config file transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/source-and-config-file-transformations#specifying-config-file-transformations). [Here are the docs on content files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files)

Comment: I've read and re-read those and tried to follow them but I am not understanding where and what the content folder is.

Comment: The content folder is in the nupkg. The target in the nuspec is the target within the nupkg, not the target in the project when installed. When NuGet installs it uses its conventions, as detailed in the docs, of what to do with various files. Note that having content copied to the project that uses the package only works when a project uses `packages.config`. Any project that uses `PackageReference` (anything using SDK projects, like .NET Core) uses `contentFiles` and is only copied at publish time, so it won't be in the project during development.

Comment: Does that mean that those transform files should not be located in the original project? (my class library)